# Unable to update data into SQL table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I got a question. When I put this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email;
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    string UserId = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

    **TextBox2.Text = email;
    TextBox3.Text = UserId;**
}
```

My data will not be saved to the database.

```
 {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_Membership SET Email = @email WHERE UserId = @id1", conn);

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", TextBox3.Text);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

But when I removed

```
 **TextBox2.Text = email;
TextBox3.Text = UserId;**
```

The data will be saved into database using above code. Can someone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors from SQL Server?  What are the types of the Email and UserId columns?  Are they large enough to contain the data you are trying to store?

Comment: no error but only the data not updated with the new 1

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, I would suggest running profiler to see what is being sent to the database. Then you can test that directly in SSMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Given you never execute the command I can't explain it.</strike>

Add

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To the end of your click method

Because you are setting the values in your page load event, they are overwriting the changed values in the controls when your button on postback. Wrap your page load code with a

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
    string email = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email; 
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(); 
    string UserId = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString(); 

    TextBox2.Text = email; 
    TextBox3.Text = UserId; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never executing your SQL so I'm very surprised that your DB is updating at all.

Take a look at the [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method.  With your current query you are creating a SQLCommand and then never running the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Connection.Open()
```

after you assign it and then

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Instead of `conn.Open` try `cmd.Connection.Open()`